# Parameterized pgf shape with optional dashed lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, shapes

Based on similar questions I found on SE, I have finally managed to create a relatively simple ‘folded document’ shape in `tikz` with a few horizontal lines inside:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{multido}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand\Repeat{\multido{}}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/folddist/.initial=10pt}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/linedist/.initial=5pt}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{document}{%
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
    \backgroundpath{%
        \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
        \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
        % main shape
        \pgf@xc=\pgf@xb
            \advance\pgf@xc by-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/folddist}
        \pgf@yc=\pgf@yb
            \advance\pgf@yc by-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/folddist}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
        \pgfpathclose
        % fold
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
        % lines
        \advance\pgf@xa by+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/linedist}
        \advance\pgf@xb by-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/linedist}
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@yc{(\pgf@yb-\pgf@ya)/8}
        \pgf@ya=\pgf@yb
        \advance\pgf@ya by-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/folddist}
        \Repeat{5}{%
            \advance\pgf@ya by-\pgf@yc
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
        }
    }
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    doc/.style={%
        draw,shape=document,
        minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1.5cm
    }
]
    \node[doc] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: code output]

Now I would like to improve it further for my needs: I would want to be able to use some kind of parameter (a PGF key?) that would make the horizontal lines dashed. I tried putting `\pgfsetdash{{6pt}{1pt}}{0pt}` before the `\Repeat` loop, but it seems that this setting applies to all the paths drawn by this shape.

My question is threefold:

1. **Should I even be defining my own shape for something like this?** I plan to use this shape as a node in a larger diagram, a chain, multiple times: with and without the dashed lines, that is why I need the parameterization
2. **How can I make only the paths of the horizontal lines dashed?**
3. **How can I create a parameter that enables/disables said line dashing?**

I would also be grateful for any other insight/simplification to my code as it does seem a little weird to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for your questions:

1. Defining your own shapes can make a lot of sense, in particular if they should come with new anchors. Alternatives include the use of `path picture`s or `append after command` but this does not always work nicely if you, say, rotate the shape.
2. You have to have two paths. I put the lines into `\beforebackgroundpath{...}`. Then you can stroke and dash those lines.
3. One way to optionally turn off and on the dashing is to use the `/.is if` key handler. Other options include setting the dash pattern in a key.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/folddist/.initial=10pt}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/linedist/.initial=5pt}
\makeatletter
\newif\iftikz@if@folderlines@dashed
\tikzset{folder/.cd,lines dashed/.is if=tikz@if@folderlines@dashed,
    lines dashed/.default=true,
    lines dashed=false}
\pgfdeclareshape{document}{%
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
    \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
    \backgroundpath{%
        \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
        \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
        % main shape
        \pgf@xc=\pgf@xb
            \advance\pgf@xc by-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/folddist}
        \pgf@yc=\pgf@yb
            \advance\pgf@yc by-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/folddist}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
        \pgfpathclose
        % fold
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yc}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yb}}
        % lines
    }
    \beforebackgroundpath{%
        \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
        \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
        % main shape
        \pgf@xc=\pgf@xb
            \advance\pgf@xc by-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/folddist}
        \pgf@yc=\pgf@yb
            \advance\pgf@yc by-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/folddist}
        \advance\pgf@xa by+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/linedist}
        \advance\pgf@xb by-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/linedist}
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@yc{(\pgf@yb-\pgf@ya)/8}
        \pgf@ya=\pgf@yb
        \advance\pgf@ya by-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/folddist}
        \iftikz@if@folderlines@dashed
        \pgfsetdash{{5pt}{2pt}}{0pt}%
        \fi 
        \c@pgf@counta0\relax
        \pgfutil@loop
            \advance\pgf@ya by-\pgf@yc
            \advance\c@pgf@counta by1\relax
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
        \ifnum\c@pgf@counta<5\pgfutil@repeat%
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    doc/.style={%
        draw,shape=document,
        minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1.5cm
    }
]
    \node[doc,fill=red] {};
    \node[doc,folder/lines dashed=true] at (2,0){};
    \node[doc,fill=blue,folder/lines dashed=true] at (4,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing, thank you! My only question is what is `folder` and whether I have to use `tikzset` instead of `pgfkeys`. It seems to me that they do similar things, shouldn’t I use one or the other? Also, thank you for ridding me of the unnecessary `multido` dependency.

Comment: @bp99 This `folder` is, ironically, a pgf folder. That is, if you declare tons of shapes, you run out of name space, so it makes sense to store these keys in subfolders. I called it `folder` but this is more like a joke, you can call it whatever you find appropriate.